# Training loss on diffusion (from "Deep Unsupervised Learning using Nonequilibrium Thermodynamics")

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

In a Paper ["Deep Unsupervised Learning using Nonequilibrium Thermodynamics"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03585.pdf), there is a development of the formula like below:
[image]

I don't quite understand the omissions in the above formula. In particular, how does it get from (11) to (12)?

Can anyone shed more light on the development of the above formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Jensen's inequality, as indicated, it follows
$$
\log
\left[ 
\int d\mathbf{x}^{(1\ldots T)} 
h \left( \mathbf{x}^{(1\ldots T)} \right)
q \left(\mathbf{x}^{(1\ldots T)}|\mathbf{x}^{(0)} \right)
\right]
\geq
\int d\mathbf{x}^{(1\ldots T)} 
\log h \left( \mathbf{x}^{(1\ldots T)} \right)
q \left(\mathbf{x}^{(1\ldots T)}|\mathbf{x}^{(0)} \right)
$$
since
$
\int d\mathbf{x}^{(1\ldots T)} 
q \left(\mathbf{x}^{(1\ldots T)}|\mathbf{x}^{(0)} \right)
=1
$ and $\log$ is concave.

Thus a lower bound of the LHS term in (11) is
$$
\int d\mathbf{x}^{(0)} 
q \left(\mathbf{x}^{(0)}\right)
\int d\mathbf{x}^{(1\ldots T)} 
q \left(\mathbf{x}^{(1\ldots T)}|\mathbf{x}^{(0)} \right)
\log h \left( \mathbf{x}^{(1\ldots T)} \right)
$$
which is (12).

Comment: Thanks for reply. One more, does $ \int q{(\mathbf{x}^{(0)})} d\mathbf{x}^{(0)} * \int q{(\mathbf{x}^{(1...T)}|{\mathbf{x}^{(0)}})} d\mathbf{x}^{(1...T)} 
 = \int {q(\mathbf{x^{(0...T)}})} d\mathbf{x}^{(0...T)} $ hold ?

Comment: I think it is a simple reorganization of the integral and use of $q \left(\mathbf{x}^{(0)}\right)
q \left(\mathbf{x}^{(1\ldots T)}|\mathbf{x}^{(0)} \right) = 
q \left(\mathbf{x}^{(0\ldots T)}|\mathbf{x}^{(0)} \right)$